# Error: Type 'MouseCursor' not found. (fl_chart)

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, project, mouse-cursor

This problem was caused by adding [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) v 0.40.0 to my *pubspec.yaml* on my Flutter project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version v [0.40.0](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart/changelog#0400) of fl_chart introduced breaking changes. A temporary solution was to downgrade to version v 0.36.4. It worked but still looking into why v 0.40.0 throws that error